# How can I make a <textarea> that fits within the width of the current viewport?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, textarea

How can I make it so that my `<textarea>` doesn't go over the border of small displays? I want that my `<textarea>` gets the width of the current display.

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 41):

You need to change its default `box-sizing` to a different value.

```
textarea {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Set a max-width on the element.

```css
textarea {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 7):

I agree with all of the above answers but one issue not addressed is that if you don't specify the number of columns the textarea will not actually fill the width of the div or element. So I use the following:

```
<textarea cols="120" style="max-width:100%;">TEXT GOES HERE</textarea>
```

I set the number of columns to slightly greater that the width of the div on a large screen and as the screen gets smaller it acts responsive to the screen size.

Comment: I like this comment, it make sense and seems to be the easiest solution

Answer (score 6):

Try `textarea {max-width:95%;}` - it will always fit your display.

Answer (score 3):

you can disable text area resize by:

```
textarea {
   resize: none;
}
```

and set max-width to the width of the container div or table

Comment: Could you edit your answer and go into a bit more detail about how to set the max width. (also, I accidentally down voted your answer and once you edit it I can give it the up vote it deserves.) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```css
div textarea {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea cols="100" rows="7"></textarea>
</div>
```

Setting both `max-width` and `box-sizing` ensures the `textarea` respects its defined width even when the number of `cols` exceeds the set `max-width`.