# How to stop this fieldset from overflowing its container?

Tags: html, css, forms, textarea

I have a css&html only form with multiple fieldsets on [codepen](https://codepen.io/fatimarahman24/pen/podrrLe?editors=1100), however only this fieldset with the `<textarea>` is overflowing on resizing the window. I tried setting a  `resize: none;` and a max-width of 95%, but nothing seems to be working.

[image]

Here is the HTML:

```
  <fieldset>
      <legend>Essay Section</legend>
      <div>
      <label for="essay_reasons">In 50 words or more explain why you want to apply for this course</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <textarea id="essay_reasons" name="essay_reasons" rows="4" cols="55" placeholder="Enter text here">
        </textarea>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
```

css:

```
/*.  generic selectors.  */

.container {
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-with: 1184px;
}

div {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
}

/*.  specific design.  */
form {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  padding: 1em 3em;
  margin-top: 10em;
  background-color: #fff;
}

input:focus {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

fieldset {
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 0.5px solid #777;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
  max-width: 95%;
}
```

Comment: I think it's because of cols="55" in your text area,

Comment: okay, let me try setting something like 30

Comment: check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39068128/how-can-i-make-a-textarea-that-fits-within-the-width-of-the-current-viewport/39068155)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Styling a textarea with the attributes `cols="value"` and `rows="value"` you will achieve a consistent styling among different browsers. But you won't have as much control compared to styling with only CSS.

I would remove your textarea `cols="55"` attribute and set the width `width: 100%` in your stylesheet:

```css
textarea {
  resize: none;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="essay_reasons" name="essay_reasons" rows="4" placeholder="Enter text here" />
```

Comment: thank you so much, that makes so much more sense.